# While loop and function return with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use 'return' function with a while loop for my Mysql query, but it returns only one result. 
I have this in my database :

```
id  name   author
1   foo    fooo
2   foo2   fooo2
```

**It returns only "2", but i want "1","2","3" ect..

Here's my code :**

```
function get_thm_cat() {
require 'database.php';
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM sk_cat ORDER BY id ASC");
$req->execute();
if ($req->rowCount() > 0) {
while ($row = $req->fetch()) {
return '<ul id="ul_cat"><li id="li_cat">'.$row["id"].'&nbsp; Name = '.$row["name"].'<br>';
} 
} 
$req->closeCursor(); 
}
```

Comment: Create an array, push the rows to the array in the `while` loop. finally return the array in the function and outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [return](http://php.net/return) you stop the execution of the function, which means that when PHP iterates over your loop for the first time and reaches `return`,  it immediately goes back to where you initially called the function. Any subsequent iterations of the while-loop are not executed and your call to `$req->closeCursor();` also isn't executed when the result is more than 0 rows because of this.

The easiest way to return multiple strings after each other is to create a temporary variable that you fill up at every iteration and return after the loop, like this:

```
$output = '';

while ($row = $req->fetch()) {
    $output .= '<ul id="ul_cat"><li id="li_cat">'.$row["id"].'&nbsp; Name = '.$row["name"].'<br>';
} 

return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` is the command to end the function and continue processing the code where it left off. You should either store the results in the `while` loop and return the array that holds these results, or you should `echo` the results in the `while` loop.

```
while ($row = $req->fetch_assoc() ) {
echo '<ul id="ul_cat"><li id="li_cat">'.$row["id"].'&nbsp; Name = '.$row["name"].'<br>';
}
```

or

```
$results = array();

while ($row = $req->fetch_assoc() ) {
$results[] = '<ul id="ul_cat"><li id="li_cat">'.$row["id"].'&nbsp; Name = '.$row["name"].'<br>';
} 

return $results;
```

Comment: Adjusted the code. In the second method you will have to add code to output the elements of `$results`.